# How to use ember cli pagination without ember data and what is the expected response?

Tags: ember.js, pagination

I want to use ember-cli-pagination but I don't use ember data. So I want to know what is the expected structure from my server, and what is the "content" property represents in the controller? does it represent the whole json response or only the array?
I expected the response to have something like

```
{
 "mylist: [
       .......
 ],
 "meta": {
   "total_pages" : 100
 }
}
```

this is what I have tried but it didn't work. Any help is appreciated.

My controller look like

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({

  // setup our query params
  queryParams: ["page"],
  // binding the property on the paged array
  // to the query params on the controller

  pagedContent: pagedArray('model.mylist',{pageBinding: "page"}),
  totalPagesBinding: "pagedContent.totalPages",

  // set default values, can cause problems if left out
  // if value matches default, it won't display in the URL
  page: 1,
});
```

Reference: https://github.com/mharris717/ember-cli-pagination

Comment: You just should define three properties at your ArrayController - where from you'll take them - no difference.

Comment: It's more dependse on your serializer / data-format

Comment: I added my controller example if this helps to give me an answer. I defined all required parameters but it seems the add-on search for "content" key or something like that !! I don't know.

Comment: contact with me in skype - looks like it will be faster )

Comment: Ok can you send me your skype username?

Comment: vasil.vanchuk  and prepare teamviewer please